# Server Can't Find Firebase Storage Default Bucket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I seem to be having some difficulty seeing why the server cannot find the bucket. I'm writing the token and other important information on a separate file as a string. Then, I'm splitting it and using the corresponding text in the javascript.

Here is the error I'm encountering.
[image]

Here is the storage.
[image]

Here is the format of the folder.

[image]

I am also using Browserify to pack the javascript into a bundle.

If anyone has solutions or advice on how to debug, it would be much appreciated!
Javascript:

Github repo: https://github.com/jpaints3/DOWNKOREFetch

```
//script.js
const firebase = require('firebase/app').default;
require('firebase/functions');
require('firebase/storage');

const fileUrl = window.location.href + 'tokensPlusAuth.txt'; // provide file location

fetch(fileUrl)
    .then(r => r.text())
    .then(t => {

        //<------------- Initialize Firebase Storage ------------->

        // access the text file with sensitive information
        console.log(t.split(/\n/));
        let tokenINFO = t.split(/\n/);

        // access firebase storage with this information
        let firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: tokenINFO[1],
            authDomain: tokenINFO[3],
            databaseURL: tokenINFO[5],
            storageBucket: tokenINFO[9]
        };

        const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        var storage = firebase.storage();

        // create location references
        var storageRef = storage.ref();
        var videosRef = storageRef.child('videos');


        //<------------- Place User Files in Storage ------------->

        function sendFiles(videosRef, dancerName, inputFiles){
            let fileName = dancerName;
            let fileRef = videosRef.child(fileName);

            fileRef.put(inputFiles).then(() => {
                console.log('Uploaded the files!');
            });
        }

        let dancerName = document.getElementById('dancerName').value;
        let inputFiles = document.getElementById('inputFiles').files;
        document.getElementById('uploadBtn').addEventListener('click', sendFiles(videosRef, dancerName, inputFiles));
    });
```

```
//server.js
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';

var express = require("express")
var logger = require("morgan")
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")

var app = express()

app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.render('index.ejs')
})

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(express.static('views'))
app.set('views', __dirname)
app.use(logger('dev'))

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`App running on http://${hostname}:${port}/`)
})

//use npm init
//use npm install --save express ejs morgan body-parser
//may need to use npm install firebase-admin
```

```
<!--index.ejs-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Upload Information</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="dancerName" id="dancerName" placeholder="Which dancer is this?">
        <input type="file" name="inputFiles" id="inputFiles" multiple>
        <input type="button" id="uploadBtn" value="Upload">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
### FIREBASE API KEY ###
'IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII'
### FIREBASE AUTH DOMAIN ###
'downkorefetch.firebaseapp.com'
### FIREBASE DATABASE URL ###
'https://downkorefetch.firebaseio.com'
### CLOUD FIRESTORE PROJECT ID ###
'downkorefetch'
### STORAGE BUCKET ###
'gs://downkorefetchvideos'
### MESSENGER_SENDER_ID ###
'IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII'
### APP_ID ###
'IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII'
### MEASUREMENT_ID ###
'IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII'


tokensPlusAuth.txt^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your api is having issues to connect in firebase. Probably this error is because he's not able to get this configuration (in that way) from a .txt file. Try doing like that

Create a const like this (generated by firebase in configurations):

```
require('firebase/functions');
require('firebase/storage');

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: <value>
  authDomain:  <value>
  databaseURL:  <value>
  projectId:  <value>
  storageBucket:  <value>
  messagingSenderId:  <value>
  appId:  <value>
  measurementId: <value>
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// rest of the code
```